# Does groupon API show deals from India

Tags: groupon

Does groupon affiliate API show deals from India? If no then any link to document mentioning that groupon api is not available for india. Specially the deals which are shown on groupon.co.in

Answer (score 0):

No, groupon.co.in does not have API for deals.

Answer (score -1):

Now they do, see the list of supported countries: https://partner-int-api.groupon.com/help/deal-api

Comment: They dont, just checked India is not in their list.